# Need help in number theory

Tags: number-theory

I wanted to know, how do I go about finding solutions to the equation $(x+1)(y+1) = z^3 + 1$ (integral solutions).

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: $z=x=y=2$ is one. Another is $x=-1,y\in\Bbb Z,z=-1$ and the symmetrical partner.

Comment: You mean integer solutions, correct?

Comment: oh yeah integer solutions, i will edit the question.

Comment: $z=x=1$, $y=0$ is another one.  In fact, if $y=0$, then $x=z^3$ works for any $z$.

Comment: any concept based solution, i was able to find these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any integer $z$ there will be a solution. If $z^3 + 1 \neq 0$, then just take $x+1$ to be a divisor of $z^3 + 1$ and let $y+1 = \frac{z^3+1}{x+1}$. This will give you all solutions for that given $z$. If $z=-1$, then either $x+1 = 0$ and $y$ is arbitrary or vice versa.

Hope that helps,

Comment: (+1) Much better than what I wrote :)

Comment: @Prism, a full parametric set of solutions would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Factor right hand side to get: $z^3+1=(z+1)(z^2-z+1)$. We have
$$ (x+1)(y+1)=(z+1)(z^2-z+1)$$
So you get a parametric set of solutions $x=z$ and $y=z^2-z$ for every $z\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But does this give *all* solutions?

Comment: @Ihf: Unfortunately not. Since $z+1$ and $z^2-z+1$ could have common factor, this parametric set will miss a lot of solutions. When $z=3$, this gives $x=3$, $y=6$, but there are other solutions, such as $x=13$ and $y=1$.